# kotlin question about distinct by multiple fileds

Tags: kotlin

Here is original list:

```kotlin
PersonList: List<Person> = {
  Person(id=1, country="US", gender="male")

  Person(id=2, country="US", gender="male")

  Person(id=3, country="CA", gender="female")

  Person(id=4, country="CA", gender="male")
}
```

**Result: distinct by country & gender**

```kotlin
result ->
listOf(
  {country:"US", gender:"male"}, 
  {country:"CA", gender:"female"}, 
  {country:"CA", gender:"male"}
)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What would the result be a list of?

Comment: i want to create list of List<String, String> (=List<country,  gender>)

Comment: `List<String.String>` doesn't exist. I suppose you would want a `List<Map<String,String>>`

Comment: oh, yes. List<Map<String,String>> is right.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you could do it:

```
fun main() {
    val persons = listOf(
        Person(1, "US", "male"),
        Person(2, "US", "male"),
        Person(3, "CA", "female"),
        Person(4, "CA", "male")
    )
    
    val result =
        persons.distinctBy { it.country to it.gender }.map { mapOf("country" to it.country, "gender" to it.gender) }
    println(result)
    //[{country=US, gender=male}, {country=CA, gender=female}, {country=CA, gender=male}]
}

data class Person(val id: Int, val country: String, val gender: String)
```